# How does Google Chrome share code across all its app versions?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, architecture, build

It seems like an aweful lot to re-implement a browser across Desktop, Android, and iOS phones. Does the Chrome team share code across these builds and how can they manage that given the different programming platforms involved.

Comment: All of those platforms support C++.

Comment: Any documentation I can refer to? Not Android/iOS, but more about Chrome's builds?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/w/list